# Returning true/nothing instead of true/false?

Tags: code-quality, language-agnostic, functions, return-type

Is it OK to have a function that returns `true`/nothing instead of `true`/`false`?

My examples use JavaScript, but I'm wondering about the general case, not attached to one specific language.

The subjects of my interest:

- Is it OK from the practical side?
- Is it OK from the logical side?

I mean, some languages provide too much freedom and personally I don't like it. I think it is better to follow the way how it works in serious languages like C++ and Java, but I never worked with them.

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;

function foo() {
    if (a === b)
        return true;
}

if (!foo())
    alert('error');
```

versus

```
function foo() {
    if (a === b)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the conceptual "type" which accepts values "true" and "nothing". It's certainly not a boolean. What is the intent? Why not  a true boolean with true/false?

Comment: In general across many languages, the question may be whether the operators handle false in the same way as nothing - notoriously, SQL is an example of a language where nothing (or null) is *not* equal to either true or false (and null does not equal null, either!). If I were you, if nothing has the same semantic meaning as false in your program, then I'd use the explicit value false, in accordance with how most people understand boolean values to work.

Comment: You can't return nothing in JavaScript. Your first example returns undefined.

Comment: @AndresF. Yes, this is exactly what I think. But I see a lot of people who have better coding skills than mine and who don't follow this way. And this is the reason of my doubts: are they wrong?

Comment: @johnc.j. What is their justification? Maybe it makes sense (though I don't see how, a priori)

Comment: @Steve Wouldn't that question be is it ok to return truthy/falsy values instead of a boolean? I understood in this case "nothing" doesn't mean false or a falsy value, otherwise the question would have been framed like that. I might be wrong, of course :)

Comment: "*I think it is better to follow the way how it works in serious languages like C++ and Java*" - sorry, but you are confusing "serious" with "type safe". Weakly typed languages have their place and are in no way "less serious" than type safe languages. When you post here question, I heavily recommend to avoid such nonsense ratings about programming languages, otherwise don't be astonished about getting lots of downvotes and close votes.

Comment: No, it's not OK, and you should write `function foo() {
    return (a === b);
}` instead.

Comment: Somewhat countering a lot of comments and answers here, assert logic specifically uses the "true or assert exception" approach **by intention**. It may not be as common in concrete business logic but that doesn't mean it doesn't serve a specific purpose.

Comment: To truly return nothing, write `return foo();` – that won't return anything!

Comment: As an aside, this behaviour can actually be somewhat observed in C++, primarily in constructs such as the ol' [safe bool idiom](https://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).  It returns either a truthy (pointer-to-member-function) or "nothing" (`NULL`) value, with the "nothing" being falsy.  Not entirely the same as this, but close.

Comment: In your specific case of Javascript, ESLint has a rule for this:  [eslint consistent-return](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return).

Comment: More usefully, how might that not be OK?

How could it be hard to see that “I cannot eat meat” and “I can not eat meat” mean the same; “I can eat no meat” almost exactly the same. Do they, or not?

"Can not eat meat" is in your context ambiguous - it clearly does not mean “able to abstain from meat”. Duh!

“Can eat no meat" is ambiguous how, exactly? My suggestion is that there’s no ambiguity at all.

Comment: Most, if not all, examples where it's valid to sometimes return a value and sometimes return "nothing", the "nothing" you're returning would in fact be null, None, nil, NULL or equivalent. So returning `true`/"nothing" is comparable to returning a Boolean `true`/`null` in Java (even if Java insists that only `false` is false, unlike some other languages, including C++, for what it's worth).

Comment: Depending on the language and tool, code checking tools might raise a warning or error if you try to return "nothing" (as in have no return statement, or an empty one) if the function returns other things, despite the code being able to run without errors.

Comment: Related discussion: https://wiki.c2.com/?ReturnBooleanEvaluations

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "OK".

In the languages that I'm familiar with that have the capability to do so, a null/nil/undefined value is falsy. That means that it would be interpreted the same as `false` when used in a Boolean operation like described in the examples. However, I cannot say for absolute certainty that this will apply to all languages for all time. I also cannot say that everyone reading and working on your code will know this, especially if it's their first foray into a language that permits this behavior.

Personally, I prefer more explicit code. Even if it's slightly more verbose or less idiomatic for your given language, easier readability and maintainability is often a superior choice. Like anything, though, it's a tradeoff that must be decided among the team building the software. Often, decisions like this can be codified in the configuration of linters and other static analysis tools and violations can be detected (and sometimes auto-corrected) during the development process.

Answer (score 7):

In Ruby, [`nil` and `false` are *falsey*, and they are the only falsey values](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Booleans+and+nil). Every other value is *truthy*, this includes `true` (obviously), but also values that some other languages might not consider truthy such as `0`, `0.0`, `""`, `[]`, `{}`, and so on.

There is also a naming convention in Ruby that methods whose primary purpose is to answer a Yes/No question are named ending with a question mark.

So, we have the method [`Integer#odd?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-odd-3F), for example, which (probably not surprising) returns `true` if the receiver is odd and `false` if the receiver is even, e.g.

```rb
1.odd? #=> true
2.odd? #=> false
```

It is, however, quite common, to convey some *extra* information using the return value of a purportedly boolean method. Actually, the most extreme example is not a method but the builtin [unary prefix `defined?` operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/miscellaneous_rdoc.html#label-defined-3F), which is a boolean operator that (at least in the most widely-used Ruby implementation) *never actually returns a boolean*!

[The Language Specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html) (section 11.4.3.2 *The `defined?` expression*) *only* guarantees that `defined?` returns a truthy value or `nil`, but it does not require that the falsey value be precisely the value `false`. And many Ruby implementations use that fact to convey additional information to the programmer. For example, in YARV:

```rb
defined? foo #=> nil

def foo; end

defined? foo #=> 'method'

foo = 42

defined? foo #=> 'local-variable'
```

This is information that is *useful* for debugging purposes, but yet doesn't hurt when you use the `defined?` operator in a conditional context like

```rb
def foo; end unless defined? foo
```

Returning `nil` (the value representing the absence of a value) instead of `false` for methods that ask for the existence of something is especially common.

In general, you are not *supposed* to do anything other with the return value than treat it as a truthy or falsey value, but you can inspect it *for debugging purposes only*.

In the Ruby community, this is considered to be completely normal, and there are methods in widely-used third-party libraries, in the standard libraries, and in the core library that do this, and the specification for those methods is often explicitly written in such a way to allow this, e.g. requiring only *truthy* or *falsey* values instead of `true` or `false`.

Comment: It's pretty rare that you'd return true/nil, though. It'd usually be true/false or informative object/nil.

Answer (score 2):

**Is it OK to have a function that returns true/nothing instead of true/false?**

- **No.**

### Statically Typed Languages

```cpp
bool isFoo( int a, int b )
{
        if ( a == b ) { return true; }
}
// Evaluated
isFoo(2, 2) // true
isFoo(2, 4) // true
```

`isFoo(2, 4)` is undefined behaviour. It will most likely return `true` because some value in memory is thrown, and as long as it has any value, it is `true`.

---

### Dynamically Typed Languages

are hard to read because you have to infer from the value, the return type.

```js
var a = 1; // Must infer that 'a' is an integer
var b = 2;

// must infer from the definition, the boolean
function foo() 
{ 
    if (a === b)
        return true;
}

if (!foo())
    alert('error');
```

Code is read more than it is written. Because of this, you should be explicit whenever possible, and never leave any ambiguity, and never craft functions with multiple return types. Keep things straight forward and decoupled.

Comment: Whether or not that statically compiled language example is undefined behavior depends on what language is involved. For some it is undefined, some will throw an error, some will refuse to compile. (I'm sure that some language out there returns a default, but I've not used one that does)

Answer (score 2):

There are three parts that must be considered: semantic, mechanic, and dialect.

Lets start with the easiest, mechanic or what works. If your language does not allow you to return nothing, you should return false. If your language does not define false you probably should return nothing, but now we are moving into dialect.

Remember code has two roles to tell the computer what to do and to convey intent to the next programmer. As you communicate with other programmers you will notice that each language develops conventions in how to communicate. There has been many a java programmer who was derided for using java conventions in C and vise versa. So unless there is specific need to communicate something explicit, follow the conventions of your language.

However sometimes you want to say something explicit. This is where the most difficult and subtle point arises. What are the semantic implications of your code. Note that there are entirely different meanings between not responding and "No" when asked if there are any problems, and each answer is appropriate in a specific context.

So think about what you are going to say and say it.

Answer (score 1):

As you're asking about this in general, it's worth considering what typed languages would make of this.

Many would be able to handle it, for instance in Typescript we might write:

```
function foo(a: any, b: any): boolean | void {
    if (a === b)
        return true;
}
```

But in C#, what would we return? The following will not compile, because not all code paths return a value:

```cs
public static bool Foo(String a, String b) {
    if (a == b) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But we could throw an error instead:

```cs
public static bool Foo(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b) {
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

So we can say that in at least some languages, the values returned from a function must be of a consistent type, or the function must throw an error.

In other paradigms, for instance in functional programming, not returning a value is strictly against the rules, though you may return a Maybe, consider this Haskell code:

```
g :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Bool
g x y
  | x == y    = Just True
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

Which would be very strange indeed.

Ultimately yes this is a question of preference but I think we can say that the type `boolean` is less complex than `boolean | undefined` or `Maybe Bool`

Comment: I like the Either line of thought for languages without exceptions.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen A good solution indeed, it seems like there are many ways to us monads for error handling

Comment: Just for completeness sake, C# *does* support `bool?`. Not that I would advocate using it in that case...

Comment: @Heinzi sorry, I don't think I'm following - C# does indeed support `bool` but every code path in the function must either return or throw a function

Comment: @OliverRadini: I mean `bool?`, also known as `Nullable<bool>`. Does my comment make more sense now?

Comment: @Heinzi haha yes of course, I missed that the `?` was in the block. [I'm fairly sure that it does.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673918/best-way-to-check-for-nullable-bool-in-a-condition-expression-if)

Answer (score 1):

Lets take an (Oracle) SQL stored function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION isEqual(
  a IN NUMBER,
  b IN NUMBER
) RETURN BOOLEAN DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  IF a = b THEN
    RETURN a = b;
  ELSE
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Then we try calling it:

```
DECLARE
  value BOOLEAN := isEqual( 1, 2 );
BEGIN
  IF value THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Equal' );
  ELSIF NOT value THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Not Equal' );
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Neither Equal nor Not Equal' );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

What do you think the output is?

> It is:
>  
>  
>  `Neither Equal nor Not Equal`

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c8aadd35f74171d2667b2c6fd0af1de1)*

Some languages there is a difference between `FALSE` and an unknown `NULL`/`nil`/`undefined` and you cannot rely on your expctations to hold when a `BOOLEAN` value can have three states: `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NULL` (undefined) and there is a semantic difference between saying a value is false or that it is undefined and you aren't sure if it is either true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that programming is not just about making the computer do what you want it to do. It's also about explaining to human readers of the code what you want the computer to do. Returning a value on some code paths and not others is confusing. It may look like an oversight to future readers.

On another note, code patterns that look like

```
if (condition) {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
```

should usually be rewritten to

```
return condition
```

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than returning `nothing`, you should return `something`.

What I meant is, independent of the programming language, your `function/method` name should define what it does inside. It's for the readability, right? The naming of your `function/method` gives some hint when somebody looks at it for the first time. If anybody wants to know what it does, he surely has to go through the whole definition but the name should give some summary first.

Now considering this fact, we always expect something from a `function/method` right? The name of the `function/method` tells us what it does and we know, "Ok, we are expecting this from this `function/method`"

So from your example,

```
function foo() {
    if (a === b)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

What we are observing is that the definition tells us that it checks if two variables are equal both in value and in type. So what do we expect?

If we ask somebody `are these two things equal?` we'll be expecting either `Yes! They are equal` or `No! They are not equal`. Meaning either `True` or `False`.

So when your fellow team member is reading your codes, s/he will expect the same thing. But if you return `nothing`, it doesn't match the expectation.

If you return `nothing` you can pretty much return `anything` right? So if we're expecting you function returns `True` of `anything` then putting it inside an `if` condition will always result in `True` and the `if` block will always get executed. *[Unles you return `None, nill, null, 0`]*

So the caller function has to handle so many scenarios. Are we getting a `float value/string value/integer value/etc...`

So that's unnecessary checking I would say!

That's why I think returning `something` is good.

In your case return `true/false` than `nothing`.

Also a tip, you can clean your code a bit by one line rather than writing a `if-else` block.

```
function foo() {
    return a === b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it okay?

**In the sense of can it work?**

**Yes.**

Depending on the language. In Java for instance you could have a method that returns 'Boolean' but in practice only either returns true or null and never false.

**Does it make sense?**

**It can, but mostly is an indication of bad design.**

It could be a representation of a case where either we know that something is true or we don't know the state of something. I.e.Let's say we teleport a drone onto a random planet. If we see a sun we know a sun exists in that solar system. If we do not see a sun, we don't know, it might be we just currently cannot see it. So a method "isThereASun" might be correct to only reply with "true" or null semantically. However, from a software design point of view that seems unnecessary complicated - any code calling cannot know that 'false' is never be the case and needs to treat null and false as separate cases. In all likelihood the logic to apply in both cases would be the same: Not put out the solar panels at the moment. 
You could make it clear in the documentation that false never happens, but that is risky (and goes against the languages ideals that you use the return value declaration to make possible answers explicit) - if someone changes the method they need to change that part of the documentation AND make sure every method calling it now covers the case.
To avoid this additional burden and make the function's behaviour clear from the onset, one could simple rename it to "doWeSeeASun" or "areSunRaysAvailable". Then the answer should always be true or false and the calling code does not need to worry about null values. (well depending on language it might need to deal with it, but a null value would indicate an unforeseen behaviour that can be dealt with at a higher level like other unforeseen behavior).

**Another valid approach**

You can also come up with your own response type, say, an enum with values "TRUE" and "NO IDEA". That would make the responses clearly defined for such cases where the answer is binary, but not true or false.